# How to handle a web element which is reported as "NOT visible" by Selenium when clicked on, in a login page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate the login process to a web application using Selenium WebDriver. I located user, password webelements, entered values using sendKeys(), then went to click on the submit button, which is throwing an exception saying that it is NOT visible.The web page html is like this ...

```
<button class="btn btn--loading login-form__btn login-form__btn--sms push-half--top clear--right float--right js-action js-action--submit js-action--submit-agreements" data-step="4" disabled="disabled" type="submit">

 <span class="btn--loading__icon loader"></span> 
<span class="btn--loading__label">Submit</span>

 </button>
```

*Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.**ElementNotVisibleException**: element not visible*

I used the code like...

```
WebElement userElement = wd.findElement(By.id(locators.get("xxxxxx.login.UNOusername.id")));
WebElement pwdElement = wd.findElement(By.id(locators.get("xxxxxx.login.UNOpassword.id")));
WebElement sbmElement = wd.findElement(By.xpath(locators.get("xxxxxx.login.UNOsubmit.button.xpath")))

userElement.sendKeys(defaultUser);
pwdElement.sendKeys(defaultPassword);

driver.sleep(2000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(locators.get("firmsoft.login.UNOsubmit.button.xpath"))));
println ("Submit button is displayed ="+sbmElement.isDisplayed()); // returning 'false'
sbmElement.click(); // throwing exception.
```

Doing this manually is no problem. As soon as I type sone few chars into password field makes the submit button, displayed and clickable.

I even tried doing hovering over the said button by this code snippet. It popped-up and looked visible,but still complained the same.

```
Actions build = new Actions(driver);
                    build.moveToElement(sbmElement).build().perform();
                    driver.sleep(5000);
```

What is the missing thing, I should take care of ?

Comment: post the relevant HTML also...

Comment: A few questions: Does the username, password & submit button resides on the main webpage or opens in a frame/iFrame or in a Modal dialogue box?

Answer (score 1):

Try using **visibilityOf** expected condition instead of **presenceOfElementLocated** and see whether it resolves the issue i.e. replace following line in your code:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(locators.get("firmsoft.login.UNOsubmit.button.xpath"))));
```

with following:

```
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(By.xpath(locators.get("firmsoft.login.UNOsubmit.button.xpath"))));
```

Let me know, if you still face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

please try below code:

```
driver.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If Selenium is giving the error for `elementVisibility`, you should always try to find out the reason using the exception in stack trace.

There could be few reasons that this error can come:-

1. Element isn't populated in DOM, in this case you have to wait for the element to appear so you can use `ExplicitWaits` by using class [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) and passing the [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)
2. Sometime there can be the case that element isn't in the visibility range may be the page is scrolled and itsn't there in the view, you can try the option to scroll the page to the element and then try to identify it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found was like this.
A.) Buttons are buried under the html code which they are making ready for both a PC and a mobile device.
B.) The button(s) tags are wrapping around 'Span' tags. And to increase the confusion, the span tags contain the text like 'Submit' or 'Login'. Meaning like

```
<button attributeslist....>
   <span attributeslist....> </span>
   <span attributeslist....>Login</span>
</button>
```

@ Secondly, the buttons are not unique. There are so many other similar buttons which are hidden and invisible. So, my xpath which I built was not reaching the exact web element.

Finally figuring this out and using the correct xpath solved the issue.